# change value in pandas dataframe using iteration

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp

I have a training data set of the following format:

```
print(data.head(5))
#Output



           0  1
0  a b c d e  1
1  a b c d e  1
2  a b c d e  1
3  a b c d e  1
4  a b c d e  1
```

It is a text classification task and I am trying to split the text "a b c d e" in to a Python list. I tried iteration:

```
data #the dataset
len_data = len(data)
for row_num in range(len_data):
    data.loc[row_num, 0] = data.loc[row_num, 0].split(" ")
```

However this doesn't work and returned the error `Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable`. Could someone help me with this problem? Many thanks!

Comment: Update your post with the output of `print(df.head(5).to_dict())`, please.

Comment: You forgot `.to_dict()`. `print(data.head(5).to_dict())`

Comment: @Corralien Adding `.to_dict()` will return a different format of output. e.g. `print(data.head(2).to_dict())` returns to `{0: {0: 'a b c d e', 1: 'a b c d e'}, 1: {0: 1, 1: 1}}` instead of a table-like output in my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `str.split`:

```
df[0] = df[0].str.split()
print(df)

# Output
                 0  1
0  [a, b, c, d, e]  1
1  [a, b, c, d, e]  1
2  [a, b, c, d, e]  1
3  [a, b, c, d, e]  1
4  [a, b, c, d, e]  1
```

Setup:

```
data = {0: {0: 'a b c d e', 1: 'a b c d e'}, 1: {0: 1, 1: 1}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: I tried your code and it return with "[a, b, c, d, e, 1] NaN" in each line instead of 1 as a label in different column with the str. If I try df.loc[0,0]=df.loc[0,0].str.split() it returns the error "'str' object has no attribute 'str'".

Comment: I checked my code with your dataframe constructor and it's work. What is your version of Pandas?

Comment: Pandas is 1.2.4. My Python is 3.8.

Comment: It should work. Can you run the 2 lines of setup and the two other code lines? Don't forget `import pandas as pd` :)

Comment: I have found the problem. I deleted the iteration and it works well. Thank you!